# SourceCookifier plugin and multi-line regex?

Tags: notepad++

I'm using the following expression:

```
^\s*(\w+)\s*:\s*(\w+)[\r\n\s]+(port|generic)
```

to find all the instances of code such as:

```
   I1 : ITT_example_design
      PORT
```

which is a multi-line result. However this doesn't work but DOES work in Notepad++'s search function. Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTags regex patterns only work on single lines of code, never on multiple lines at once. Thus, you would need to implement your needs [in the parser itself](http://sourceforge.net/p/sourcecookifier/svn/HEAD/tree/sourcecookifier/ExuberantCtags/css.c).

Answer (score 1):

First of all the `[\r\n\s]` in your regex is useless since `\s` is a superset of `[\r\n]`. So it can be simplified to `^\s*(\w+)\s*:\s*(\w+)\s+(port|generic)`.

Notepad++ & SourceCookifier/CTags use different regular expressions engines. N++ uses PCRE while CTags uses POSIX style (I'm not 100% sure for the latter, can anyone confirm?).

So the character classes `\w`,`\s` won't apply in SourceCookifier case. Change them to the appropriate `[:word:]`,`[:space:]` respectively.

So your regex should be something like that:

```
[[:space:]]*([[:alnum:]]+)[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*([[:alnum:]_]+)[[:space:]]+(PORT|GENERIC)
```

Comment: ok so i took your advice and switched my REGEX to   ^[[:space:]]*([[:alnum:]]+)[[:space:]]*\:[[:space:]]*([[:alnum:]]+)[[:space:]]*[[:cntrl:]]+[[:space:]]*PORT           but it found nothing?  What am i missing?

Comment: 1) Try to add an asterisk after `[[:cntrl:]]*` instead of plus 2) I think you are missing an underscore `[[:alnum:]_]` (check my answer) 3) if none of the above works, try to "decompose" the regular expression, and by that I mean try firstly to check if `([[:alnum:]]+)` matches anything, if yes then add up, until you achieve the desired result.

Comment: correction:            ^[[:space:]]*([[:alnum:]]+)[[:space:]]*\:[[:space:]]*([[:alnum:]_]+)[[:space:]]*[‌​[:cntrl:]]+[[:space:]]*PORT        doesn't work

Comment: Did you changed the `+` to `*`? Try to remove the `^` too.

Comment: Yes i tried both those things.  If i break the expression down like you suggestion everything works fine up until i add any letter after the final [[:cntrl:]][[:space:]] with whatever combination of +/* i use.  It truly seems like ctags simply cannot see multiple lines of code at once which seems so odd to me! :(

Comment: OK, so you are saying that this: `^[[:space:]]*([[:alnum:]]+)[[:space:]]*\:[[:space:]]*([[:alnum:]_]+)[[:space:]]*‌` works? Right? And the problem starts when you add `[[:cntrl:]]`. Then just don't add it! Are you sure you need it? Just to be clear, `[[:space:]]` **already contains newline** characters! It is equal to `[ \t\r\n\v\f]` in N++.

Comment: Ok so that DOES clarify quite a bit..i also learned that i shouldn't be using [[:space:]] for spaces but instead use [[:blank:]].  This is my new expression that btw still doesn't work ==> [[:blank:]]*([[:alnum:]_]+)[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*([[:alnum:]_]+)[[:space:]]+p    It's the 'p' that still kills it.  Also i found this link which seems to indicate i need to use ctags with a special flag to do what i want.  Any idea if this is possible with the plugin?  https://sourceforge.net/p/ctags/bugs/285/

Comment: Also how are you highlighting your code in the comments like that??

Comment: About ctags and this special tag, I'm afraid I don't have an answer. I have never used ctags nor sourcecookifier. About the inline `code`, use backticks "`" around your code and it will render as code.

Comment: I appreciate your trying to help even if we couldn't find a solution!

Comment: This is what SO is all about :)